# LINQ Distinct on a particular property and latest

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have the following collection

```
public class User
{
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}

var users = new List<User>
{
    new User {  SSN = "ab", StartDate = new DateTime(2021, 01, 01) },
    new User {  SSN = "ab", StartDate = new DateTime(2021, 01, 02) }, // take this

    new User {  SSN = "ac", StartDate = new DateTime(2021, 01, 01) },
    new User {  SSN = "ac", StartDate = new DateTime(2021, 02, 01) }, // take this

    new User {  SSN = "ad", StartDate = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01) },
    new User {  SSN = "ad", StartDate = new DateTime(2021, 01, 01) },
    new User {  SSN = "ad", StartDate = new DateTime(2022, 01, 01) }, // take this
};
```

What I am trying to do is to get SSN distinct but by only latest StartDate and I created two queries which seems to work. There is a better way in term of perfomance?

```
// shows only latest is selected
var district = users
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.StartDate)
    .GroupBy(g => g.SSN)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();

var ssn = users
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.StartDate)
    .GroupBy(g => g.SSN)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .Select(x=> x.SSN)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Are you want to return the result with the `StartDate`? If doesn't need to return the `StartDate`, why not just `Distinct()` the name.

Comment: For some reason I need to include also the StartDate

Comment: This is pretty [straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72936743/361177), you just need to do it in the good order `distinct` then `latest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you also need the latest `StartDate` in the comment,

Group by `SSN` and get the latest `StartDate` via `.Max()`.

```cs
var result = users
    .GroupBy(g => g.SSN)
    .Select(x => new User
    {
        SSN = x.Key,
        StartDate = x.Max(y => y.StartDate)
    })
    .ToList();
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z7Hyia)

Comment: This will not be easily maintainable it the `User` object grows some new properties. See [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72936743/361177).

Answer (score 2):

For better performance you should avoid `OrderBy()` like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72936689/1025555) does.

But you can also avoid creating a new `User` instance with [`MaxBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-6.0):

```cs
var latest = users
    .GroupBy(u => u.SSN)
    .Select(us => us.MaxBy(y => y.StartDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I am trying to do is to get `SSN` distinct but by only latest `StartDate`:

You just need to do the operation in the good order.
First group by `SSN`.
Then get the latest element (by `StartDate`) in each group:

```csharp
var result = users.GroupBy(u => u.SSN)                     // distinct
                  .Select(g => g.MaxBy(u => u.StartDate)); // latest
```

Comment: This unnecessarily sorts each group. `MaxBy()` is faster. See [my reponse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72936842/1025555).

Comment: .NET6 rules !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you group by `SSN`, and then select the same `SSN`, the values of `StartDate` are completely irrelevant.

Hence, the list of distinct SSNs can be obtained by selecting the `Key` of each grouping, like this:

```
var ssns = users.GroupBy(u => u.SSN).Select(g => g.Key);
```

Update: As per your further comments, if you need the whole user object, which has the maximum `StartDate`, you can do something like this:

```
var users = users
    .GroupBy(u => u.SSN)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(u => u.StartDate).First());
```

For another solution, see also [Yong Shun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72936689/245183).

Comment: That is correct but it was request and can be used in the future...